# Adding values of SQL count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which echos back some SQL counts for each user using foreach. I want to have a total which will add up all the counts foreach. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
 $students = get_course_students($course->id, 'lastname');    
    $toggle=0; 

if (!empty($students))  {
    foreach ($students as $student) {

$user=get_record('user','id',$student->id);

$atriskcountrecords = count_records_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mdl_ilp_tutorial WHERE template = 2 AND user = $user->id AND course = $course->id");
$personalcountrecords = count_records_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mdl_ilp_tutorial WHERE template = 1 AND user = $user->id AND course = $course->id");
$reportscountrecords = count_records_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mdl_ilp_reports WHERE user = $user->id AND course = $course->id");

echo '<tr class="r'.$toggle.'">
<td class="cell c'.$toggle.'" valign="top" nowrap="true" align="left">'.fullname($user).'</td>
<td class="cell c'.$toggle.'" valign="top" align="center">'.$atriskcountrecords.'</td>
<td class="cell c'.$toggle.'" valign="top" align="center">'.$personalcountrecords.'</td>
<td class="cell c'.$toggle.'" valign="top" align="center">'.$reportscountrecords.'</td>
</tr>';

if($toggle==0)$toggle=1;
else $toggle=0;         

}
}   

echo'<tr>
<td><strong>Totals</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>(TOTAL)</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>(TOTAL)</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>(TOTAL)</strong></td>
<td></td>
</tr>';


echo'</table>';
```

Comment: As an aside, you _really_ shouldn't mix server side logic with view layer markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I really understand your question, it's quite easy ; just declare a variable per counter before your foreach loop and increase it with count value.
For example :

```
$atriskcountrecordsGlobal = 0;
if (!empty($students))  {
    foreach ($students as $student) {
        ...
        $atriskcountrecords = count_records_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mdl_ilp_tutorial WHERE template = 2 AND user = $user->id AND course = $course->id");
        $atriskcountrecordsGlobal += $atriskcountrecords;
        ...
    }
```